# Question about flagging topics that are a valid Q but also have a seperate main topic...

Tags: discussion, duplicates, flagging

If you ask how to add a quicklist to a launcher and get it answered ([Case in question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39900/how-to-quicklist-for-deadbeef)) and it then gets included into a main topic with several examples of how to add quicklists to a myriad of other launchers ([Case in question 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity)) would that merit flagging the question? As a dupe or as a 'more complete topic'(?) Even though the question by itself is valid.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not only valid, it is the source of the quicklist. IMHO, the best option would be for the posts in lists such as the quicklist one to link back to their sources where applicable. They are also good for searches, as the question solving your exact query (in the case of 'deadbeef quicklist') comes before the more generic list in the search result. If you go by the generic list, you have to search in the list as well.

Not to mention that other possible solutions would be left out if the original question was closed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate view of this would be to close the First question as a duplicate, then merge the answer into the quicklist question. Thereby giving the original answerer credit for the work via upvotes.